# Using ActiveForm without bootstrap template in Yii2

Tags: yii2

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

How can I get the input text box without bootstrap 3 wrapper codes ?

I am using a custom HTML wrapper and how can I implement my own template for the text box ?

thanks

Comment: you want to use your css design??

Comment: yes, I dont want to use bootstrap CSS. I want to use my own classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends whether you want to change div's class or input itself.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'title', ['options' => ['class' => 'custom_class_div']])->textInput(['class' => 'custom_class_input']) ?>
```

I have given two `options` with overwriting classes from bootstrap.

`custom_class_div` will replace boostrap for div (input's parent). `custom_class_input` will replace boostrap for input. Basically, it removes `form_group` in both cases but in first option it will remove that part where input field takes entire "line" in parent div and in second option this will modify input itself (will still be just 1 input on the "line" but no border shadows, smaller input field, etc.).

If you don't have any classes but just want to use style in div/input element, you can replace `class` with `style`, for example:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['style' => 'width: 150px']) ?>
```